# Best way to protect sensitive information copying in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, security, web, copy-protection

The company I work for has a requirement to protect some area where articles are rendered, I've implemented some procedures to protect web-scraping but the problem remains for manual scraping.

The anti web scraping bot protection mechanism seems to be working good so far, but I see clients trying the manual scraping.

What I have tried to protect the article contents:

1. Set a copy eventhandler on article's wrapper element to prevent copy.
   -> Clients can make use of userscripts (greasemonkey, etc) to efficiently bypass this by removing the eventhandler or simply making scripts to copy the contents and save to a file
2. Developer console protection -> useless
3. Redirect if F12 pressed -> useless

Seems like protecting HTML is **undoable** (unless someone tells me otherwise) so I'd like to know other ways to display text and render it totally UNABLE to copy.

Things I've thought:

1. JS detection mechanisms to diagnose if the user has any sort of userscript running, in other words, if there's no malicious JS code being injected and executed to extract the text
2. Transforming the article's HTML into a PDF and displaying it inline with some sort of anti text-select/copy (if this even exists).
3. Transforming the article's HTML into chunks of base64 images which will render the text completely unable to select and copy

Are there any good ways to prevent my content from being stolen **while not interfering** much with user experience? Unfortunately flash applets are not supported anymore, it used to work charms that era.

EDIT: Cmon folks, I just need ideas for at least make end user's efforts a bit harder, i.e. you **can't** select text if they're displayed as images, you can only select image's themselves.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a great question. Lol, but today scrapping ins't even relevant anymore because you will never fully achieve it, for example it would take me less than 15 minutes or less to retype a 1500 worded article. Not to even mention images/videos... they're all available as soon as your browser has rendered your page.

Comment: Yeah you can't stop a person from just retyping whatever they see. But you could institute a "pay wall".

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you  ship HTML out of your machine, whoever gets it can mangle it at leisure. You can make it harder, but not impossible.

Rethink your approach. "Give information out" and "forbid it's use" somewhat clashes...

Answer (score 2):

**No, You Can't**

Once the browser loaded your page, You **can't** protect the content from **copying** / **downloading**.

It can be **text**, **image** or **videos**, You can protect it from unauthorised access. But you can't protect from get scraped by the authorized person.

But you can make it harder using the steps that you mentioned in your question and restricting the **copyright laws**.

*This issue still exists in many sites, Especially In E-learning platforms, such as udemy and etc... In those sites, The premium courses are still getting copied / leaked by the person who bought it.*

**From Udemy FAQ**

> For a motivated Pirate, however, any content that appears on a computer screen is vulnerable to theft.  This is unavoidable and a problem across the industry.  Giants like Netflix, Youtube, Amazon, etc. all have the same issue, and as an industry, we continue to work on new technology solutions to limit Piracy.
>
> Because pirating techniques currently outpace protection, we hired a company who is specifically dedicated to enforcing the DMCA laws on your behalf and target violating individuals, hosting sites, and DNS servers in an attempt to get any unauthorized content removed.

Comment: See my edit, I want at least to make their life harder. You can select html text, but you can't select text in an image. I'm talking about a database full of laws, my job is to prevent them to get copied or at least make the thief's life very hard.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned in my answer, You can make it harder, But you can't prevent. Because I can type out the text what I see in image. And there are a lot of online sites / tools to extract the text from image. They will scan the image and extract the text using ML/AI

Comment: Any idea of a PHP library with good support for HTML/CSS to generate images?

Comment: Refer this, https://phppot.com/php/how-to-convert-text-to-image-using-php/